# Select all rows created this week (starting Sunday)

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, unix-timestamp

Edited with partial answer:

Basically, I want to select only today's rows, not the last 24 hours, and I want to select July's rows, not the last 31 days (7/1/13 -> 7/31/13, NOT 6/25/13 -> 7/25/13).

This is what I'm using to select only today's rows. I use America/Los_Angeles as the placeholder for the user's specified timezone (that will be filled in using PHP). The "timestamp" used below is just a standard MySQL timestamp of when the row was created.

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE convert_tz(timestamp, 'UTC', 'America/Los_Angeles') 
>= DATE(convert_tz(NOW(), 'UTC', 'America/Los_Angeles'));
```

For the week's records, I would still get the current date in the user's timezone using `DATE(convert_tz(NOW(), 'UTC', 'America/Los_Angeles'))` but I'm not sure how to get the first day of the week from that, e.g., today's date returns 7/25/13, but the first day of this week was on 7/21/13.

For the month, I could take today's date, use the MONTH() function to grab only the month, then create a new Date object by doing

```
str_to_date(
      concat( MONTH( [today's date from above] ), 
             ' 01', 
             ' 2013'),
      '%m %d %Y'
)
```

And that would give me the first day of this month. The same could be done for this year's rows if need be.

Anyway, that only leaves rows created this week. WEEKDAY() might be useful but I'm not sure.

Comment: Have you tried extracting just the date portion of the datetime variable?

Answer (score 1):

"Since midnight" is the current date without a time. The MySQL function for the current date without a time is [`CURDATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate), and the function to turn a date, time or timestamp to a UNIX value is [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp).

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE Ftimestamp_column > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE());
```

Also note that the MySQL equivalent for the PostgreSQL `date_trunc` function is [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date).